# Read a png file and feed a cnn Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, png, decode

I am trying to build a simple CNN using Tensorflow. The problem is that I am not able to read a simple .png file to feed the CNN.

```
>>> filename = tf.constant("training/a1.png")
>>> filename
<tf.Tensor 'Const_1:0' shape=() dtype=string>
>>> image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
>>> image_string
<tf.Tensor 'ReadFile_1:0' shape=() dtype=string>
>>> image_decoded = tf.image.decode_png(image_string)


>>> image_decoded
<tf.Tensor 'DecodePng_1:0' shape=(?, ?, ?) dtype=uint8>
```

As you can see on the above code. The tf.image.decode_png( image_string ) returns a tensor of shape unknow.

Thanks [vladimir-bystricky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8315956/vladimir-bystricky)! I got it. Here is the code it may help another people.

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> filename = tf.constant("training/a1.png")
>>> image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
>>> image_decoded = tf.image.decode_png(image_string)
>>> shape = tf.shape( image_decoded )
>>> sess = tf.Session()
>>> print(sess.run( shape ) )
[360 360   4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is right behavior, because in your code you only create a graph, and TF doesn't realy read the png file on this step, but only creates operation which will do it, when you launch Graph in the Session. Results of operation is Tensor with unknown shape (on this moment). You can resize or crop it in predefined sizes.